# How do I turn a double into a percentage in Java?

Tags: java

I have a double called average. If its output is 0.8266666531562805 how do I format it to display as 82.67%

Current line:

```
System.out.println("Your score is: " + average);
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("Your score is: %.2f%%%n", average * 100);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. It may not be very satisfying, but that's an answer

Comment: Here's a link that can explain it in _way_ more depth than I could: [Class Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##%");
df.format(0.8266666531562805);
```

Comment: Johnny Mopp gave a "better" (more general) answer: `System.out.printf("Your score is: %.2f%%%n", average * 100);`, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html.  See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: "Better" is a matter of opinion.  My opinion it his answer is more difficult to read and isn't as maintainable.   The only issue with the Formatters supplied by Java is they might have issues with thread safety, but that's easily handled if it proves to be an issue.

In my opinion, my answer is "better".